# What format of font size does Google Docs use?

Tags: google-docs, font

Probably a silly question but couldn't find an answer anywhere. Does it use point? So font size 12 = 12pt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Google Docs, Google Sheets, Google Fonts, etc. use **`px`** as font size representation.

**`pt`** is (should be) used only in printing/press due to significant difference in cross-platform visualization:

[image: 0]

[image]

---

Here are some good explanations of the difference between **`pt`** and **`px`**:
**https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference**

Comment: And yet, Google Docs is a word processor, so it's kind of directed more towards printing / press isn't it? I believe MSWord measures fonts in points, as do most Word Processors

Answer (score 0):

The font size settings in Google docs, sheets, etc. are in POINTS, not pixels. You can easily verify this for yourself with a simple web page containing some 11-point text and some 11-pixel text. Paste the following block of html in a blank file and save it as test.html, then open it in your web browser alongside a google doc that uses size 11 Arial font. The 11-point text will look the same as size 11 text in the google doc. The 11-pixel text will be tiny by comparison. Editorializing about how things should or shouldn't be doesn't change this. Google Docs uses POINTS.

```
<html>
  <body style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif">
    <p style="font-size: 11pt">This fascinating text is 11 points.</p>
    <p style="font-size: 11px">This fascinating text is 11 pixels.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```